# achieve formatting in email body(using html)

Tags: html, email, html-email

I am trying to achieve formatting in the email body like line break etc.for this i am using the following code:

```
<a href="mailto:someone@example.com?Subject=Hello%20again&body=Hi!!!Vin<br />/r/nSUB">
```

I tried br,/n,/r but all the three are getting rendered as it is. can some body help me out in this.

Answer (score 0):

Use `%0D` (a URL-encoded carriage return):

```
<a href="mailto:someone@example.com?Subject=Hello%20again&body=Hi!Vin%0DSUB">
```